# Are my female guppies preagnant

Tags: guppies

[image]
Is my female guppy pregnant
I think she is but I'm not sure I have another guppy who is about as big 
Also there stomachs look black inside are those the baby's
And if anyone could tell me that would be great

Comment: Hey Matthew! Please don't ask the same question twice.  Please use the link in the above comment to view your other question (which I answered the other day).